# Copy file permissions, but not files

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, copy, chmod

I have two copies of the same directory tree. They almost have the same files in both (one version may have a couple extra or missing files). However, most of the files are in common to both directories (have the same relative paths and everything).

Assume these are in directories:

```
version1/
version2/
```

The problem is that the permissions in version1/ got messed up, and I would like to copy over the permissions from version2/, but do it without replacing the files in version1/ which are newer.

Is there an automated way to do this via bash? (It doesn't have to be bash, it could be some other method/programming language as well).

Comment: I created a new question in ServerFault related to this topic: [Copy file permissions, but not files in Unix](http://serverfault.com/questions/665237/copy-file-permissions-but-not-files-in-unix)

Comment: I think this is a great question as do others, as evidenced by over 100 up-votes on Question and Answer. If you can't reopen this question at least migrate it to Unix & Linux where it would be more appreciated. I don't have sufficient rep here to nominate for reopening but hopefully OP does.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should have a look at the `--reference` option for [`chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod):

```
chmod --reference version2/somefile version1/somefile
```

Apply `find` and `xargs` in a fitting manner and you should be fine, i.e. something like

```
 ~/version2$ find . -type f | xargs -I {} chmod --reference {} ../version1/{}
```

This even works recursively, and is robust against missing files in the target directory (bar the *No such file ...* errors, which can be ignored). Of course it won't do anything to files that only exist in the target directory.

Cheers,

Comment: Just to confirm, in the command above, it is changing version 2 to match version 1 and not vice versa correct? Finally, this is robust against missing files?

Comment: No and no, respectively.

Comment: To elaborate, it copies the perms from current dir to version1, and I'm unsure whether `xargs` will continue if there's no matching file in the target directory - you should test before running on your live FS.

Comment: I got curious and tested, see amended answer.

Comment: Note, however, that this won't copy ACLs, which are used to set more fine-grained permissions that chmod.

Comment: note that `--reference` is a GNU feature, not POSIX, so `chmod` may not have it in all systems.

Comment: To make the command recursive to reach all sub-folder: `chmod --reference version2/somefile version1/somefile`

Comment: I could save a Fedora installation by copying permissions from the live CD. Still works, 9 months later. Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a great answer as do others, as evidenced by over 100 up-votes on Question and Answer. If you can't reopen this question at least migrate it to Unix & Linux where it would be more appreciated. I don't have sufficient rep here to nominate for reopening but **hopefully you do**.

Answer (score 10):

You could use this script (it changes the permissions recursively but individually for each file/directory)

```
#!/bin/sh
chmod --reference $1 $2
if [ -d $1 ]
then
    if [ "x`ls $1`" != "x" ]
    then
        for f in `ls $1`
        do
            $0 $1/$f $2/$f
        done
    fi
fi
```

Run the script with arguments version2 version1

Comment: I know this is five years old but I'm wondering if you recollect testing this at the time you posted it. I want to give it a try but don't want to muck anything up copying, pasting and running it as is without a little confirmation first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
chmod owner-group-other ./dir or ./file
```

Unless permissions are fine grained and different from one file to another, you could do a recursive chmod on the directory and unify the permissions.

See man chmod for references on the options that might be useful