# How to copy only file permissions and user:group from one machine and apply them on another machine in linux?

Tags: shell, file-permissions

I have a list of files (absolute path of files/folders) stored in a text file. I need to copy only the permissions, user:group attributes (of all those files) from one machine and apply the same settings on the same set of files on another machine.

One way I can think of is to do it manually one by one, by checking the attributes on one machine and doing chmod/chown on another machine file by file but that seems to be a tedious task.

Any idea of how to automate this ?

edit: Just wanted to make clear that I don't need the data of these files from the source machine because the data is different in source machine. Target machine contains the updated data, only thing that I need now from source machine is file/folder permission and user:group.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy file permissions, but not files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245144/copy-file-permissions-but-not-files)

Comment: That questions was to copy permissions on the same machine using chmod --reference. This question is how to copy permission across machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
#!/bin/bash

user="user"
host="remote_host"

while read file
do
    permission=$(stat -c %a $file) # retrieve permission
    owner=$(stat -c %U $file) # retrieve owner
    group=$(stat -c %G $file) # retrieve group

    # just for debugging
    echo "$file@local: p = $permission, o = $owner, g = $group"

    # copy the permission
    ssh $user@$host "chmod $permission $file" < /dev/null 

    # copy both owner and group
    ssh $user@$host "chown $owner:$group $file" < /dev/null

done < list.txt
```

I am assuming that the list of the files is saved in "list.txt".

Moreover you should set the variables "user" and "host" accordingly to your setup.

I would suggest to configure ssh to have "automatic login". Otherwise you should insert
the password twice per loop. Here a good tutorial to do this [SSH login without password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).

Another solution that establishes just one ssh connection and uses the recursive option
for the directories (as asked in the comments) is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

user="user"
host="remote_host"

cat list.txt | xargs stat -c "%n %a %U:%G" | ssh $user@$host '
while read file chmod_par chown_par 
do
    # $file contains %n
    # $chmod_par contains %a
    # $chown_par contains %U:%G

    if [ -d $file ]; then
            chmod -R $chmod_par $file
            chown -R $chown_par $file
    else
            chmod $chmod_par $file
            chown $chown_par $file  
    fi
done'
```

Comment: +1. Thank you very much for the answer. Really helpful. I need to modify it a little bit to differentiate between files and directories. for directories I have to add -R.

Comment: Another point I thought of is, instead of doing ssh for every file. lets write chmod and chown in a temporary script file and transfer and execute that script on the target machine. Doing this we need to provide password may be at most 2 times, once for scp and another for ssh. Hope it'll improve it a little bit.

Comment: You are perfectly right. The first solution, although very easy to understand, is not efficient. The second one should be faster. If your set of files/directories is big enough and you have time, I would be curios to know the improvement of the second version wrt to first one. Thanks!